# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'company_id'; check that column/key exists")

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations, django-mysql

When I migrate, i always get it error. First, I created the table and then dropped it. Now when I created the table again. I am facing this issue. It also does not create the columns.

**Model.py**

```
class AssociateCompany(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="associate_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name="associate_company", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

It does not Create the column, user_id and company_id, and displays the folling **error:**

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'company_id'; check that column/key exists")

Comment: Delete the migration files and migrate again

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the py file in the migrations folder and comment out the erroneous remove in the operations list operate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed that works.
step1: comment the line giving that error from the models
step2:delete that particular migration file i.e 0003.faied_migrations.py
step3: run `python manage.py migrate --fake`
step4 run `python manage.py makemigrations` you can also attach the app_name e.g `python manage.py makemigrations accounts`
step5: run `python manage.py migrate` or `python manage.py migrate mainapp`

[Readmore here](https://www.hostingbyalitech.com/blog/post/solved-djangodbutilsoperationalerror-1091-cant-drop-column_name-check-columnkey-exists)

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to solve this is to remake the database from scratch.

1. If you are using SQLite. Delete the file and delete all files from the migration folder and try creating the migration file again.
2. If you are using MySQL or PostgreSQL delete all the tables and try again. don't forget to delete the migration files else this won't
   work.
   This problem arises when you had a foreign key and you deleted the column without removing the depending data.

Comment: Hi @hrtj123, I don't see how this is a solution. It's like saying if you want to fix a car, just make it disappear and get a new one. :-)

Comment: It is a sort of solution for beginners. NOT for production.